# Why i'm getting a function instead a value of my UID of the currentUser on Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic4

When i'm doing console.log on a method which one SHOULD return the uid of the current user, it return the function. why?

Different methods i tried to get UID:

1. this is value of current user:

   ```
   function () {
       return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
   }
   ```
2. this is the value of the current user:

   ```
   function () {
       return this.user.uid
    }
   ```

What is the correct one? Why cannot get the value? When i create the user uid the method is the next:

```
  const res = await this.afAuth.auth
                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)

  this.afstore.doc(`/users/${res.user.uid}`).set({
    username
  })
```

Comment: well.. did you tried `return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid();`

Comment: Yes i saw it at the end, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY RESOLVED:

At the end the only method who returns me the value, was:

```
getUID() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid
}
```

I was following the wrong tutorial...